# Using Typescript + ngMock modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to wrap my head around Typescript, AngularJS, and the ngMock portion. I've seen code to inject a module at the beginning of a unit test like this.

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module("myApp"));
```

I need to provide another service so this works:

```
beforeEach(module("myApp", function($provide) {
    $provide.value("myService", {
        ...
    });
}));
```

But if I did

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module("myApp", function($provide) {
    $provide.value("myService", {
        ...
    });
}));
```

The Typescript compiler complains that angular.mock.module only takes one argument. So in the first snippet above, what module is it using? When I go to the definition, it says in the angular-mocks.d.ts:

```
declare var module: (...modules: any[]) => any;
```

So what is going on here? I'm not sure if I understand the notation in the definition file to understand if `angular.mock.module` and `module` are used the same. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: is "myApp without end quote a typo?

Comment: @Edminsson ya just a typo.  Writing pseudo code.  Will fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not sure if I understand the notation in the definition file to understand if angular.mock.module and module are used the same. Can someone explain this to me?

There is an error in the definition. The following two should be the same: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular-mocks.d.ts

```
    // global module
    declare var module: (...modules: any[]) => any;

    // from angular.mock.module
    module(...modules: string[]): any;
    module(...modules: Function[]): any;
    module(modules: Object): any;
```

If you get the latest definition file its been fixed: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/pull/2564

**There is a flip side**: In quite a few cases the definitions are even *better* than the JavaScript lib's documentation.